# In a family with 6 children, the probability of (a)having three children of each sex? (b)having four of one sex and two of the other sex?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a family with 6 children,

**a.** What is the probability of having three children of each sex?

**b.** What is the probability of having four of one sex and two of the other sex?

I know in this problem I have to use $P(n,r) = \dfrac{n!}{(n−r)!}$. For part **a.** I think it will be $P(6,3) = 6\times5\times4$ but I'm not sure how would I do part **b**.

Comment: Probability should be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Hint: Use the Binomial Distribution and consider the two cases in part b.

Answer (score 1):

(a) This follows the binomial distribution. If the probability of having a boy is the same as the probability of having a girl, then it is $\binom{6}{3} (\frac{1}{2})^{6}$. The $\binom{6}{3}$ term chooses the boys.

(b) This is similar to part (a). To choose the boys, we have $\binom{6}{4} * (\frac{1}{2})^{6}$. However, there is a symmetry case for the girls, so we multiply this by $2$. Note $\binom{6}{4} = \binom{6}{2}$, so multiplying by $2$ gives us the same quantity as if we considered the case of choosing $2$ boys.